# Can Spring's @Value annotation be used with types implementing BeanPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring

As mentioned in the [javadoc for `@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

> you cannot use `@Value` within `BeanPostProcessor` or `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`types

But it works fine for me

```
@Component("emp")
class Employee implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    public Employee(@Value("pankaj") String name) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This is printing out

```
pankaj
```

What am I missing?

I also tried expression and it also works:
In `Employee` class above putted

```
@Autowired
    public Employee(@Value("#{example.name}") String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    }
```

And Example class is like this

```
@Component("example")
public class Example {
    public static String name="Abc";
}
```

This printing out

```
Abc
```

I tried with property resolution and it also works for me:
**propfolder/abc.properties**

> example.name=pankaj dubey
>   **spring.xml**

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="spring.tst.beans"/>
 <context:property-placeholder location="propfolder/abc.properties"/>
```

Updated `Employee` class with below code

```
@Autowired
    public Employee(@Value("${example.name}") String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Comment: Here we can use @Value but we should not use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc is referring to the property resolution feature of the annotation. For example, you might have

```
@Value("${example.pankaj}")
```

where you'd expect Spring to inject the value of the property with key `example.pankaj` (from some property source). In your example, that won't happen. Instead, Spring will inject the value

```
${example.pankaj}
```

literally.

Comment: Tried SpEL also its working...Edited above question.. Thanks

Comment: @PANKAJDUBEY The javadoc is referring the property resolution. The SpEL expression resolution is a whole other process.

Comment: Thank You for you support. I tried with property resolution also and it still works for me.. edited above question once again..Actually  I also referred "In Getting Started With Spring Framework By Ashish Sarin @ page #227" here in note its written that "@valu annotation is processed by a BeanPostProcessor; therefore, you should not use @value annotaionin component classes that implement BeanFactoryPostProcessor or BeanPostProcessor interface."